# Copy Picture to Clipboard

Tags: android

I have read previous posts on how to copy text to the clipboard. However, my purpose is to copy a picture, from an ImageView in this case, to the clipboard.

I know how to save an ImageView to a file using a Bitmap/Canvas/OutputStream. Now I want to know how can I save that picture to the clipboard.

I am guessing there has to be some simple method such as (follow pseudocode):

```
Bitmap image = get_image_from_image_view();

clipboard_instance.setClipboardContents(image);
```

I find no reference to this in the Android Clipboard or Clipboard Intent documentation.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, my purpose is to copy a picture, from an ImageView in this case, to the clipboard.

That concept does not exist in Android. You can put text, a `Uri`, or an `Intent` on the clipboard, not an image.

Depending on where the image originated from, you could put a `Uri` pointing to that image on the clipboard. Whether anything will be able to paste something useful from this `Uri` depends a bit on the receiving application.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. So let's suppose that I, for example, wanted to copy a picture from my app so I can paste in the email application, let's say. How would one go about doing this, in generic terms, on Android ?

Comment: @VascoPatricio: Step one would be to write an email application that supports pasting of images. I suspect that there are approximately zero of these. Given that you wrote your own email application that supports pasting of images, you know what you are expecting to see on the clipboard (e.g., a `Uri` pointing to the image, coming from a `ContentProvider` so that the MIME type is correct). Creating the program that copies the image to the clipboard for your own email application to use is simply a matter of following the same protocol.

Comment: I see. My goal was to load an image from a URL, and then allow the user to do multiple things with it, one of which is copy to clipboard, so he could then use on email/multimedia applications/phone image editor/etc. 

Given the restrictions in this case, I think it's far more useful to just copy the picture URL to the clipboard. Then the user might as well download the picture and do what he wants with it afterwards.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Principally it is possible to :
1. Save image to a file and then to use newRawURI
2. Stream bitmap into parcel and insert into intent.
But in both of the cases there must be an additional handler code which will process the clipboard content.